# C# NameValueCollection: Should we check if key exists before we remove those?

Tags: c#, namevaluecollection

We want to remove few keys from a NameValueCollection but we are not sure if they actually exist in it or not.

If i try to remove key1 which isn't in NameValueCollection, there's no exception/side-effect:

```
nameValues.Remove("key1");
```

But what is ideal way to do this, should we check if key exist before removing it?

Comment: As the documentation states: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

If the key is not found the collection will remain unchanged

Comment: Checking the key first will be inefficient, since you will be doing two lookups (one when checking, the other when removing). Just go ahead and remove it without checking first - unless you want to consider it an error if the key is not present; then you'll need to check it first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. You don't need to check the key before trying to remove it.
No exception is thrown if the key doesn't exist.

I believe you should not do that because of it cause you O(n) * 2 operations.

- O(n) for checking
- O(n) for trying to delete

Comment: Checking is O(1) as far as *trying* to delete. Delete is O(n)